# Creating a parallelizable DiscretePlot

Tags: plotting, parallelization

To my knowledge, [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscretePlot.html) cannot be parallelized, although one can simulate the default behavior of `DiscretePlot` and get the benefits of parallelization with a combination of [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html) and [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelTable.html).  For example.

```
f[x_]:=(Pause[0.5];x^2);
DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, 0, 2, 0.2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[ParallelTable[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 2, 0.2}], 
  Filling -> Axis] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem with this alternative is that we lose access to several useful [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscretePlot.html) options: [`ExtentMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExtentMarkers.html), [`ExtentSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExtentSize.html) and [`ExtentElementFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExtentElementFunction.html).  How can we simulate the behavior of these options in [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html) so that we may preserve the benefits of parallelization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ClearAll[discretePlot];
SetAttributes[discretePlot,HoldAll];
discretePlot[args___]:=
    Block[{System`DiscretePlotDump`flatTable},            
        SetAttributes[System`DiscretePlotDump`flatTable,HoldFirst];
        System`DiscretePlotDump`flatTable[expr_,eval_,{var_},{vals_}]:=
            ParallelTable[expr,{var,vals}];
        DiscretePlot[args]
    ];
```

Comment: How could I have missed System`DiscretePlotDump`flatTable?  Brilliant.

Comment: @bobthechemist Yep, that's the first thing that comes to mind - you probably just forgot :)

Comment: I don't actually get an improvement in `AbsoluteTiming` using this function on bob's example.  Should I?  v7 issue?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Very likely, V7 issue. Can't check, don't have V7 handy.